Transforming lighttp configuration into nginx : something wrong for some redirects?
I deployed raspap with its webui. It uses by default lighttpd and I would like to change for nginx but it seems some assets (e.g. logo) fails to be loaded and the links loop back to the index page which I believe is due to a redirect issue.
The functional lighttpd configuration as defined by raspap is given below
50-raspap-router.conf
server.modules += (
        "mod_rewrite",
)

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/(?!(dist|app|ajax|config)).*" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( "^/(.*?)(\?.+)?$"=>"/index.php/$1$2" )
    server.error-handler-404 = "/index.php"
}

With this configuration, it works. I do actually have both lighttpd and nginx running at the same time to check that the website is indeed functional.
The nginx configuration I'm using,

server {
    listen 8090;

    # root and index can be set according to your setup
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    # URL Rewriting
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }

    # Exception for static files/directories like dist, app, ajax, config
    location ~ ^/(dist|app|ajax|config) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # PHP handling
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock; # Adjust as needed
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # Error handler for 404s
    error_page 404 = /index.php;
}

It partly loads the index page but some assets fail to load and the links on the menu, e.g. Dashboard which points to http://192.168.1.135:8090/wlan0_info loops back to the index page.
The logo on the top left has the URL : http://192.168.1.135:8080/app/img/raspAP-logo.php  . It fails to display with my nginx config but is successfully displayed with the lighttpd configuration.
More precisely, for the index page, with NGINX, it is displayed as :

The expected display when logging on the web console is :

If I try with the NGINX configuration below
server {                                                                                                               
        listen 8070;                                                                                                               
        root /var/www/html;                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                      
        location ~ \.php$ {                                                                                                                           
                include fastcgi_params;                                                                                            
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;                                                                                     
                fastcgi_index index.php;                                                                                                     
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                         
}  

The assets are succesfully loaded but the links in the menu point to a 404. Therefore, I believe there is something wrong in my redirection directives
    # URL Rewriting
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }

    # Exception for static files/directories like dist, app, ajax, config
    location ~ ^/(dist|app|ajax|config) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

